# Inner Plot Margin with Default XTS Plot

Tags: r, plot, xts

When plotting an XTS object without any custom `par` attributes, I get a margin *within* the plot box (or "plot area" going off of http://research.stowers-institute.org/efg/R/Graphics/Basics/mar-oma/index.htm):

[image]

(It is hard to see due to white on white, but there is another maybe 20px or so between plot box (the box with the solid black line) and the edge of the image).

How can I adjust the margin within the plot box?

Comment: Are you referring to the area between the solid black line and the orange points?  Adding a red arrow or bracket to the image you posted would clarify which margin you're talking about.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: Yes.. that is the area I am talking about it, will update soon...

Comment: I thought so. Your explanation was good, but it's just so hard to be precise in words when talking about all of the different areas involved in constructing an R plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could fix this by setting `yaxs="i"` in your call to `plot()` or `plot.xts()`

`yaxs` and `xaxs` specify the methods used to calculate the extent of the plotted axes. `yaxs="r"` (the default) is to extend the axis a bit beyond your minimum and maximum y-values. `yaxs="i"` plots axes that just cover the range of your data (or the supplied value of `ylim`) with no additional buffer.

It's not pretty, but this example will show you the difference:

```
require(xts)
par(mfcol=c(1,2))
data(sample_matrix)
plot(as.xts(sample_matrix))
plot(as.xts(sample_matrix), yaxs="i")
```

If you want even finer control over the range plotted, you might want to use `yaxs="i"` in combination with `ylim=extendrange(range(yvalues))`.

Comment: In my case I wanted `xaxs="i"`, but same idea.